# Template engine useful if using angular?

Tags: angularjs, templates, pug, single-page-application, ejs

i am building a single page application using node.js and angular.js.

I wonder if there is any advantage on using a template engine like jade or ejs since angular has the ng-include directive which let you inject html partials inside your main html page, and of course with angular you have two-way data binding. Any thought on this?

Comment: short answer is,  other than syntax preference, not really

Comment: Sometimes I feel its overly hyped, what coffeescript is to javascript, template engine is for html markups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s good idea to use Jade (or another template engine) for all html pieces in your project even if you’re creating SPA with AngularJS. Jade allows you to generate templates easy and fast. Templates will be neat and easy-to-read.

As for include directive, stick to the following rule in Angular+Jade projects: use Jade’s include for reusing pieces of html when you create static templates, use ng-include for dynamic purposes when partials depend on the App’s state.

Comment: Thanks for your point, it is interesting to differentiate between static and dynamic partials using jade include and angular ng-include..i will think about it.